# How to make a video with dynamic content (such as current local time while playing)?

Tags: video, synthetic-media

In https://thechoiceisyours.whatisthematrix.com/ teaser, irrespective of the video played due to pill selection, they call out the local time in the video. How do we do something similar?

One Option was to generate videos for every combinations, as in create a 1440 videos for every minute and play them.

Is there any other options where we can dynamically generate video based on parameter? Something like saying making a character say a name?

Answer (score 2):

Looking in devtools the video is a complete mp4 video. So it appears that they generated the videos (or generate them on the fly). If you reuse the mp4 URL from devtools the time does not update.

**Possible solution:**
They probably stitch together 3 video segments: the `beginning`, the `<time>`, and the `end`.

Example:
https://thechoiceisyours.whatisthematrix.com/generated/v7/high/17f66df49088448668a250e51bbfa3de.mp4

Comment: PS: Since the 3 segments would each start on a keyframe, it should be easy to dynamically replace bytes (eg: some `concat` function) before sending final data to the video player. If they are even more clever, they don't just edit at the MP4 level (replacing key/frame bytes) but would actually edit the NAL units to replace the macroblocks or slices in the H264 video.

Comment: Any tool which can do the dynamic stitching?